# NodeJS Spawn not Firing Arguments

Tags: node.js, npm, spawn

I'm building a system which uses `spawn` to run commands as specified by an array that's read in from a file. Everything is working fine when I use test commands (like `echo Something`), however when I set the command `npm install express -save` the `stdout` is what you get if you enter `npm` without any arguments.

Here' the code processing the commands:

```
var runProcess = function (process, buildDir, callback) {
  console.log('Running command: ' + process);
  var args = process.split(" ");
  var command = args[0];
  var proc;
  var stdout;
  var stderr;

  // Set arguments by shifting array
  args.shift();

  // Spawn the command
  if (args.length) {
    if (command === 'npm') {
      proc = spawn(command, [args, "--color", "always"], {
        cwd: buildDir
      });
    } else {
      proc = spawn(command, [args], {
        cwd: buildDir
      });
    }
  } else {
    proc = spawn(command, [], {
      cwd: buildDir
    });
  }
}
```

If at any point I `console.log` to check if it's getting into the right place it traces correctly, but the output is always just the `npm commands` dump with the usage information as if it's not reading the arguments.

Comment: [args, "--color", "always"] - are you sure it doesn't just include the array as one of the arguments, instead of joining them together?

Comment: yeah, I had it just as a singluar `[args]` previously, it does the same thing regardless of the additional flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting your types mixed up as @maxorq suggests. You want a single array containing only strings. You are nesting arrays. Try this:

```
  proc = spawn(command, args.concat( "--color", "always"), {
    cwd: buildDir
  });
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. It's weird, because I pulled this from an almost identical script that worked just fine.